# How do I add social media icons in my bigcartel sidebar?

Tags: html, css, icons, sidebar, bigcartel

I'm new to bigcartel, however I roughly know how to use HTML/CSS. I can't find anywhere to insert social media icons in my sidebar, I'd like to make all of my platforms consistent this way.

How would I add custom icons into the sidebar, underneath my logo?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use font icons [fortawesome.github.io](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)